# CodeIgniter download a file to windows via FTP

Tags: php, codeigniter, ftp, download

In my website I have the following 2 functions. The first one takes the FTP connection and creates a directory in the specified path. server.com/Host_path/DirectoryName for example. This piece of code works perfectly fine. I have an upload function that uploads file test.txt to the folder DirectoryName and the second function is supposed to download that file to my local Windows machine. However i get the error message `Unable to download the specified file. Please check your path.` With no indication as to which path is wrong.

```
$path = 'server.com/' . $result['path'];
$this->ftp->mkdir($path);
```

When I echo the remote and local paths I get `remote = server.com/Host_path/DirectoryName/test.txt and local = C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\test.txt` . Based on the fact that the above function works but the below function does not, I believe that the Windows path is wrong but it could be a difference in functions.

```
$remotePath = 'server.com/' . $result['path'];
$localPath = 'C:\\Users\\Owner\\Desktop\\test.txt';
$this->ftp->download($localPath, $remotePath, 'auto');`
```

Please Help!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12331563/forcing-file-to-download-in-codeigniter-ftp-class

Answer (score 0):

For remotePath, use absolute path starting with "/"

Comment: Didnt work. I'm using CodeIgniter so there should be some way to do it using base_url() or something.